# unbalanced panel data to long format

Tags: r, panel-data

I have a panel data with varying length in multiple files. One file includes observations for several participants and several metrics for each in the following format

| X | M_1.ccc | M_1.ccc.1 | M_1.ccc.2 | M_2.ccc | M_2.ccc.1 | M_2.ccc.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. |
| 2 | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. |
| .... |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 20 | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. |
| 21 | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. |  |  |  |
| 22 | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. |  |  |  |

I need that table in the long format which is

| Wave | id | ccc | . ccc.1 | ccc.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. |
| 2 | 1 | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. |
| .... |  |  |  |  |
| 20 | 1 | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. |
| 21 | 1 | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. |
| 22 | 1 | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. |
| 1 | 2 | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. |
| 2 | 2 | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. |
| .... |  |  |  |  |
| 20 | 2 | XXX. | XXX. | XXX. |

I am trying to use`panelr` package and `long_panel` function there: https://jacob-long.com/post/panelr-intro/, but not so many examples there

This try does not work

```
> long_panel(data_full, prefix="_", wave=X)
```

and when I put periods (which are different for every participant) tere is a missing starting point...

```
test<-long_panel(data_full,
              prefix="_",
              wave=X,
              begin=1,
              end=2)
```

Well, it is not actually 1 but should be empty... and it returns error:

> Error in if (ncol(nn) != 2L) stop("failed to guess time-varying variables from their names") :
> argument is of length zero

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Sample data:

```
dat <- structure(list(X = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), MLC_1.c3d = c("12.061268", 
"12.166716", "12.292454", "12.439793", "12.608850", "12.799803"
), MLC_1.c3d.1 = c("-1.138404", "-1.275099", "-1.402655", "-1.523949", 
"-1.642789", "-1.761063"), MLC_1.c3d.2 = c("9.136170", "9.374666", 
"9.601912", "9.818493", "10.023846", "10.217005"), MLC_1.c3d.3 = c("87.739037", 
"88.746254", "89.675377", "90.512108", "91.259438", "91.935745"
), MLC_1.c3d.4 = c("25.202179", "25.669239", "26.133680", "26.592773", 
"27.045420", "27.492346"), MLC_1.c3d.5 = c("-7.886568", "-8.132847", 
"-8.310396", "-8.435491", "-8.530880", "-8.623341")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you please include your sample data as code so we can load it in the same form as you have it? e.g. using `dput(head(YOUR_DATA))` and including the code that outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to pivot longer with the {tidyr} package.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  rename("Wave" = "X") %>%
  pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "id", values_to = "val") %>%
  separate(id, c("id", "key"), sep = "(?<=MLC_\\d).") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = key, values_from = val) %>%
  mutate(across("id", str_replace, "MLC_", "")) %>%
  arrange(id, Wave)
```

I'm sure there is a way to do it in one step, but I haven't figured it out yet. Will update this answer if I work it out.

### Update

This is neater, pivoting done in one-shot:

```
dat %>%
  rename("Wave" = "X") %>%
  pivot_longer(-1,
               names_to = c("id", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "MLC_(\\d.*).(c.*)",
               names_transform = list(id = as.integer)) %>%
  arrange(id, Wave)
```

Comment: Paul - related to the question above but still extra - i need to brush off my regular expressions - i always stumble over them helplessly. what is the best resource? apart from practice-practice-practice?

Also, any cheatsheet? to put it on the wall and look at it every free minute?

Comment: This is the one I look at every time: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using `data.table` (assuming your data is named `df`).

```
library(data.table)

setnames(setDT(df), "X", "Wave")

melt(df, 
     id = "Wave", 
     measure = Map(function(x) paste0("MLC_", 1:2, ".", x), c("c3d", paste0("c3d.", 1:35))),
     variable.name = "id")
```